# memory read failed for 0x0 on MacOs and flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

I want to run my into my physical Iphone and get *memory read failed for 0x0*
but in simulator is working fine.
Any one can help me Plaese?

```
Xcode build done.                                           15.2s
Installing and launching...
(lldb) 2023-12-05 11:29:03.963824+0300 Runner[730:74728] [VERBOSE-2:FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(35)] Using the Impeller rendering backend.
Warning: Unable to create restoration in progress marker file
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0000000000000000
error: memory read failed for 0x0
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
Error launching application on iPhone.
```